# What is the idiomatic word for processed foods?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

Ramen instant noodles are a famous dish among college kids, as they are cheap and easy(and fast) to make. However, people say that they are unhealthy, and might cause illnesses in the long run, if consumed regularly.

Say I am a parent, and I have to tell my kids that they can't have instant noodles, because they are harmful for their health. How would I say that.

> Ramen noodles are pre-cooked foods.
> Ramen noodles are processed foods

What word can I use I place of precooked and processed here?

Comment: A common expression for food which is tasty but not very healthy is **junk food**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say "fast food" as an implication of processed food, "convenience food" or "prepackaged food".

But "processed food" is a phrase that is not that hard to understand, you can just explain simply how it is "changed/processed over and over again".